# Exclusive run application for (Alt-)Linux without dependency of abnormal termination

Tags: linux

I want ensure the application is not launched twice on the same computer but I failed.

My task is to port our application from Windows to UNIX-like systems. At least to Alt-Linux (`uname -srvoi` shows:
`Linux 2.6.32-el-smp-alt27 #1 SMP Tue Sep 20 19:35:51 UTC 2011 unknown GNU/Linux`).

For Windows I just create file in write mode and with ban for writing for other applications. On application exit I close the file and delete it. If application crushed or forcibly terminated it is OK because file stay existing but system allows to me to create it again.

For Alt-Linux I already tried:

1) `fopen` file and `lockf` it 
- result: `F_TEST` hangs second instance of application instead immediately return with error. Probably it is because file system is nfs and cannot lock files. (No, I cannot select other file system. App should work on nfs too.)

2) `fopen` file and `flock` it 
- result: the same

3) `open` file with `O_CREATE|O_EXCL` flags (mode is `0666`)
- result: OK until I forcibly terminate first instance. As result file stay on disk and I cannot start application again.

4) `unlink` file and immediately `open` it with `O_CREATE|O_EXCL`
- result: just does not work. I can start second instance (yes, I know in UNIX 'unlink' removes file only from directory but keeps on disk until first instance closed file handle)

5) Use `shm_open` with `O_CREATE|O_EXCL` flags
- result: as in 3)

6) Use `shm_unlink` + `shm_open` with `O_CREATE|O_EXCL` flags
- result: as in 4)

7), 8) Use `sem_open` with `O_CREATE|O_EXCL` flags with or without `sem_unlink` before
- result: as in 3), 4)

10) Use `sem_open` with `O_CREATE`, without `O_EXCL` but use `sem_trywait` after 
- result: OK until I forcibly terminate first instance. As result semaphore stay with value 0 and application cannot start again. I can delete semaphore but I do not know how to distinguish 2 situations:
- semaphore is 0 because application is already running
- semaphore is 0 because application crushed

Below sample code:

```
int main()
{
  sem_t *sem= sem_open("/a.out.sem", O_CREAT, 0666, 1);
  if (sem != SEM_FAILED)
  {
      printf("success\n");
      if (0 == sem_trywait(sem))
          printf("trywait ok\n");
      else
          printf("cannot trywait\n");
  }
  else
      printf("failure\n");
  for(;;)
  {
      sleep(1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Start application and abort it with `^C` to imit situation of application is killed before can call `sem_post` and/or `sem_unlink`.

What can I do?

Upd:
Possible solution suggested to me in LJ: use open + unlink to create file on start and delete file on exit, write PID to that file and use kill(0, pid) to additional check if process crushed/killed if file exists.

Comment: file lock should work on local filesystem, for example `/tmp`.

Comment: it seems you didn't try `fcntl`: http://serverfault.com/questions/66919/file-locks-on-an-nfs

Comment: Set a signal handler to perform cleanup if the process is interrupted. Then several of the approaches above will work just fine. If somebody bypasses the cleanup handler with `kill -9` you'll have to teach them not to (but then they should not  have such privileges in the first place before they learn proper manners).

Comment: As I read fcntl is called by flock and lockf whose are wrappers above fcntl.

Comment: Yeah, best foolproof is to make fools smarter, but I still hope Linux with files is cool enough, at least not worse than Microsoft's OS :)